# Ansible pip virtualenv installation fails with missing setuptools

Tags: python, ansible, virtualenv, setuptools

I found a lot of articles/questions related to ansible pip + virtualenv but nothing could riddle me this:

Trying to setup a "simple" virtualenv with python, this task completly fails:

```
---
- hosts: local
  connection: local
  tasks:
    - name:
      apt:
        pkg:
          - python3
          - python3-pip
          - python3-setuptools
          - virtualenv

    - name: Install some pip packages in virtualenv
      pip:
        name: requests
        virtualenv: /opt/somevenv
        virtualenv_python: python3
        virtualenv_site_packages: yes
```

which results in

```
root@my-pc:/some/path# ansible-playbook test.yaml 

PLAY [local] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [apt] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Install some pip packages in virtualenv] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "No setuptools found in remote host, please install it first."}
    to retry, use: --limit @/some/path/test.retry

PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

on a Debian 10 with python 3.7.3 currently installed and ansible using python3

```
root@my-pc:/some/path# ansible-playbook --version
ansible-playbook 2.7.7
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible-playbook
  python version = 3.7.3 (default, Jan 22 2021, 20:04:44) [GCC 8.3.0]
```

Also pip3 has setuptools correctly installed:

```
root@my-pc:/some/path# pip3 show setuptools
Name: setuptools
Version: 40.8.0
Summary: Easily download, build, install, upgrade, and uninstall Python packages
Home-page: https://github.com/pypa/setuptools
Author: Python Packaging Authority
Author-email: distutils-sig@python.org
License: UNKNOWN
Location: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
Requires: 
Required-by:
```

And in addition python3 usage is forced:

```
root@my-pc:/some/path# tail -n3 /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg 
# context = 3
[py3-hosts:vars]
ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python3
```

Does anybody have an idea why it is failing?

Strangly, when doing an

```
# apt install python-setuptools
```

everything works fine ... I really don't get the point why in background somehow python2 is used, although python3 is setup even for ansible.

Comment: Hi TinkererZen welcome to SO. You have `hosts: local, connection: local` in your playbook but `py3-hosts:vars` in `ansible.cfg`; that doesn't align for two reasons: (1) I don't believe ansible.cfg is consulted for any `vars` contributions, perhaps you're thinking of an inventory file (2) even if it was, unless you added `localhost` to the group `py3-hosts` it wouldn't consult those vars anyway. Adding an explicit `vars: { ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python3 }` to your playbook is the cheapest experiment to see if that's what is wrong. Good luck

Comment: @mdaniel Thanks! That was indeed working, but still I will check on it. Ansible runs with python3, but chooses python2 ... strange. Thx anyway! :)